# My .jsp file from a STS workspace always opens in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-setup

My .jsp file from STS workspace always opens in VSCode.
I accidentally opened jsp file once in VSCode, as a result of a double click on jsp file from within the STS workspace but now that association is sticky and it always opens it in VSCode although my work/file is sitting inside STS.

Where is this association stored inside VSCode and how to clear the same so that all my files, when working inside STS, open inside STS.

STS = SpringsourceToolSuite

Comment: If this is Windows, choose Start and then type Control Panel. Choose Programs > Make a file type always open in a specific program. If you don't see Programs, choose Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the jsp file -> "Open With" . Please Select "text editor" option

Comment: yes, but  is possible change the default behavior? Is needed to install any plugin?